# CSS background color does not display when duplicating template to development

Tags: html, css

I acquired a template that includes a html css tag to set the background color of the page to #ececec.  I have compared the original template against my recreation, and in my recreation, the background is white.  Screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why even though the css is there and in its proper location in the css hierarchy, that the backgrounds are different?

thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is an element more in the forefront that has a white background? I'm thinking check the body element or even your div "login_page_wrapper".

Comment: Check what styles are applied to `body`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest giving the `body` tag your background color instead of the `html` tag. After all, it's a bit weird to style the head section of an HTML document along with the body. Also, if all else fails, use `!important`. This can help diagnose what your problem really is. Code:

```
body {
   background: #ececec !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks much!.  I have noidea why the originator of the design pushed it to html. I put it in the body tag and boom....it worked.  Thanks much

Comment: Haha! Yeah, that's weird... Glad it worked for you!

Comment: I'm a programmer, and totally suck at UI design.  so I have to use other people's design (referecing themeforest.net).  he did that one.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Well, good luck in your design endeavors!